# Magento Rest: how to get orders by modification date

Tags: magento, rest, magento-1.8

How to get magento orders filtered by modification date with help of Rest Api?

now i use GetOrders api call with filter: `filter[1][attribute]=created_at&filter[1][from]={xxx}&filter[1][to]={xxx}` , but i need something like:

```
filter[1][attribute]=modified_at&filter[1][from]={xxx}&filter[1][to]={xxx}
```